# AWS - Basic tutorial on beanstalk - cannot bootstrap

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I'm working on getting my Cloud Practitioner's cert and i've done all the lessons and feel pretty good about the exam. I would like to do all of the practical applications and started with the most basic one on [elastic beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/guides/deploy-webapp-elb/). The problem is that the beanstalk tutorial requires the use of [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/guides/setup-cdk/) on setting up your cdk and bootstrapping your account.

Literally the first time i've heard of bootstrapping. I guess it makes sense, but it's pretty annoying to come across something for the first time in a practical application.

So, I ran the command and got an error ...

```
cdk bootstrap aws://00xxxxxxxxxx/us-east-2 --profile storygraf

Environment aws://00xxxxxxxxxxx/us-east-2 failed bootstrapping: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::00xxxxxxxxxxx:user/storygraf-builder is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStacks on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:00xxxxxxxxxx:stack/CDKToolkit/* because no identity-based policy allows the cloudformation:DescribeStacks action
```

Why do I need a policy to do bootstrap additional info to resources to which I already have permissions to interact?

If it is necessary to set up a policy, why isn't that discussed in a tutorial? How do I do this? Where? How do I know that I did it right? After all, i'm not actually interacting with a resource yet, so how can I set a policy?

Why isn't this mentioned anywhere else? Am I expected to have already done this? I feel like I am missing something when it comes to IAM and the command line and it is really frustrating not be able to do basic tutorials.

Comment: It looks like the pages you linked to indicate a need for administrator access but the `storygraf-builder` IAM user you're using doesn't have certain required permissions, including, but not limited to, `cloudformation:*`

Comment: Admin access to what? I don't understand what the resource in question is?

Comment: You created a local AWS credentials profile named `storygraf`. What permissions did you give the associated IAM user (`storygraf-builder`?) that you set up and that this profile represents?

Comment: I just gave it access to an s3 bucket that it is pushing code to. My issue is that I don't know what permissions to give as I don't understand the resource being accessed? Is it just a blanket cloudformation access?

Comment: I appreciate your help @jarmod. I created a key pair for my admin account and used those credentials and it worked. However, I still don't understand how to do this with a non root IAM user.

Comment: As mentioned previously, the docs seem to indicate an administrator, so see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_job-functions.html#jf_administrator). That’s almost certainly more permissions than required but simplifies the setup for a beginner.